# Linking multiple replies with dealer and router in ZeroMQ

Tags: node.js, zeromq

Am new to zeromq and my learning it, I know if you want many services linked to many repliers you use the `req -> router -> dealer -> rep` architecture. Now the problem is I have many separate repliers each handling their own function, e.g. `test1`, `test2` and so on and I want to use the architecture where I have one `req` which decides which service to use say `test1` then communicates to `router -> dealer -> test1`. This is how I understand it if am wrong please correct me, so far I only know how to make router -> dealer, how do I go about doing this in a simple node code of all involved parties, `test1` and `test2` can have multiple instances, any help will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two different things.

First, you have to be able to communicate through your tasks in bi-directional way. That's the router -> dealer architecture.

Second, you have different type of clients, that can handle different calls *(func1, func2 ...).*

[image]

Red is type 1, orange type 2 and blue type 3 in the schema.

---

What I would do is to makes the clients identify themselves to the server after they connect.

**"hello, I'm a client type 1"**, so the server will have somewhere a map when it knows which client handle which calls. And then send messages directly to the right client.

Comment: Ok thanks for this explanation, it really cleared things up, also are there any blockers in zeromq, as in, I have implemented that model, but after sending like 2-3 request, the next one is not going through, is it like if there is one that failed or delayed sending reply the next one won't go through??

Comment: You should not have issue with the message sending